# What is the meant destination when using the phrasal verb "drop by" without object?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I found an example sentence in Collins dictionary when searching for the phrasal verb "drop by":

> She and Danny will drop by later.

Where will she and Danny drop by? Is it the speaker's/listener's home? Can it be neither the listener's nor the speaker's place?

Comment: The sentence doesn't specify the place. It would depend on the context.

Answer (score 2):

It probably means "drop by here", or it could mean "drop by there" in context.

Of course, where "here" or "there" means depends on where the speaker and listener are. If both are at work, it might mean "come and visit me at my desk", for example.

But very often, "here" or "there" would be the speaker or listener's home.